# overflow-y: hidden but should enable mouse scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, overflow

I have used `overflow-y: hidden;` in my css to disable vertical scroll-bars. But still I need to allow users to scroll up and down through the mouse wheel.

How do I allow ONLY mouse wheel vertical scrolling but remove showing scroll-bars using `overflow-y: hidden;` ?

Any suggestions are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're wanting to achieve this without JS?

If that's the case, one approach is to hide the scrollbar by offsetting it outside of a parent/wrapper element. So for example:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child">
        <p>Your content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    height:200px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child{
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    padding-right: 25px; //This amount will differ depending on browser. It represents the width of the scrollbar
    overflow-y: scroll;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

In your css/scss file add to main-component that scrolable and without scrollbar.
In my case it's ***"page_customers"***:

```
page_customers {

    ::-webkit-scrollbar,
    *::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
    }

    /*... some css/scss ...*/

}
```